# Search a word in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a `String` like ,

```
 String test = "voiceemailchat";
 String find = "chat";
```

I have to check the new word is already present in the existing word or not.

The condition looks like ,

```
if(test has find)
      //go something
else
      //go somethig
```

Is it possible in java or not ?

Comment: Have you looked into this ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: This is not a stupid question, it's just that it looks like you did not try.

Comment: Sorry for asked a simple question. I flaged the question.I realized my mistake.

Comment: It's not that it is simple, it just looks like you didn't try. -8 is pretty harsh to be honest. Get used to reading the JavaDocs for things. Look up String in it and see what can be done. I never did this when I started and getting the hang of it made a HUGE difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```
String test = "voiceemailchat";
String find = "chat";

if(test.contains(find)) {
    //string found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about -

```
if(test.indexof(find)>-1){
  ... // found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a first step Always look in Javadocs. for `String` click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

You can use any of these methods: [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

Execute following code. If you have large data file or string use regular expression. It is best.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "voiceemailchat";
      String pattern = "chat";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found the value");
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [String#indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf)

```
if(test.indexOf(find)!=-1){
   ... // value is found
}
```